# Trouble with Play Framework Security

Tags: java, playframework

I am brand new to the Play framework, but I am trying to use the secure module and cannot get it to work.

**Problem 1**
Eclipse cannot resolve Secure.Security:

```
package controllers;

import models.*;

public class Security extends Secure.Security {

    static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        User user = User.find("byEmail", username).first();
        return user != null && user.password.equals(password);
    }    

}
```

**Problem 2**

> NullPointerException : Cannot get property 'check' on null object.

When I have the following in my view:

```
#{if secure.check}
...
#{/if}
```

I have added the security module to my configuration.  What am I missing?

```
module.secure=${play.path}/modules/secure
```

Comment: Can't help you specifically, but I know Matt Raible has been "playing" with Play for a while now. Check out some of the posts on his site regarding his experiences if you are interested - http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/play_2_0_a_web as a starter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to command line at your project folder and write these :

```
play clean // Clear previous compiled classes
play deps --sync // Add & Update missing dependencies like secure module
play eclipsify // You must run eclipsify again to show secure libs to your project
```

then go to project in eclipse , right click and refresh. Restart again.

Single Line Command :
  **play eclipsify --deps --sync**